# Notation: "belongs to" with an R subscript

Tags: notation, cryptography

I've run into an expression:
$x_i \in_R \mathbb{Z}_q$
– and I wonder what this means.

An example paper is [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.146.1073&rep=rep1&type=pdf), here's example in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_veto_network).

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If no one answers, you may consider providing more context, or even a reference.

Comment: Oh, sure. References are added. The topic is cryptography.

Comment: Just a guess: $\in_R$ means chosen randomly.

Answer (score 2):

$x \in_R S$ means $x$ is chosen uniformly randomly from $S$. This notation is common in cryptography papers. For example, this notation is defined in the beginning of section 2 of [Proofs that yield nothing but their validity and a methodology of cryptographic protocol design](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/X/gmw1c.pdf).