# Mathematical notation for choosing an element randomly from a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a nonempty set $\mathcal{S}$ with finite number of elements. Is there any mathematical notation to randomly choose an element $x$ from the set $\mathcal{S}$ ?

Each element in the set $\mathcal{S}$ has got equal probability (uniform probability) for getting chosen.

Comment: In stead of using notation, just say it in words.

Comment: I don't know in what situation you want to use a notation. Usually it's best to express such things in words. But if you really need a notation, make one up (e.g. $S x \in A$) and be clear about what it means when you introduce it.

Comment: I want to use this in my journal paper in an Algorithm block. Yes, ofcourse I can define a new choosing function $\psi$, s.t. $s = \psi (\mathcal{S})$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x \in_R S$ is a common way to denote that $x$ is chosen randomly from the set $S$. See, for example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506096/notation-belongs-to-with-an-r-subscript).

Comment: How do you say, N samples were randomly drawn from set S?

Comment: I might write this as $x_1, …, x_N \in_R S$.

Answer (score 7):

I've seen a $S \xleftarrow{R} x$ used as a notation in protocol or crypto system descriptions, for drawing uniformly random elements $x$ from a set $S$.

Comment: Yes I have seen it too in crypto courses.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of logic, $S \neq \emptyset \implies \exists x[x \in S]$. The idea of picking an item from the set in a proof would involve assuming some particular instance of an item. An example of how that might work in a proof is as follows:

\begin{array}{l}
& S \neq \emptyset & \text{ Premise }\\
& \exists x[x \in S] & \text{ $S \neq \emptyset$ }\\
& a \in S & \text{ Assumption (some typical $a$) }\\
& \text{ ... Prove something, such as $P(a) = \frac{1}{|S|}$ ... }\\
& a \in S \land P(a) = \frac{1}{|S|} & \text{ $\land$ Introduction }\\
& \exists x[x \in S \land P(x) = \frac{1}{|S|}] & \text{ Existential Introduction }\\
\end{array}

The advantage of thinking of it this way is that the rule (*Existential Elimination*) for discharging such assumption is well [defined](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348269/eliminating-rule-of-existential-quantifier). Basically, it involves ensuring that the conclusion drawn from the assumption is valid independently from the particular instance assumed.